# Coldfusion 11 REST Service works with HTTP but not HTTPS (404)

Tags: apache, web-services, rest, tomcat, coldfusion

I'm trying to take advantage of Coldfusion 11's REST Services, but I can only get it working with HTTP, not HTTPS. When I change the protocol to HTTPS, it returns a 404.

The steps I have taken:

1) I made a folder in web root called "api-test"

2) Inside that folder, I created a file called "animals.cfc" containing:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/animals">
        <cffunction name="getAnimals" access="remote" httpmethod="GET" produces="application/json" returntype="struct">
                <cfset value = { "cats": "dogs", "birds": "snakes" }>
                <cfreturn value>
        </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

3) In **Coldfusion Administrator** under **Data & Services / REST Services**, I added "/web/webapps/api-test" as the *root path* and "api-test" as the *mapping*.

4) In my web browser, while logged into one of my CF web applications on the same server (using HTTP), I test the API with jQuery and Firefox's Firebug / Web Developer plugin:

```
$.get("http://cftestapp1.mydomain.com/rest/api-test/animals");
```

The data is returned without a problem

5) In my web browser, when I change the protocol of the CF web application to HTTPS, and retry the same command but with HTTPS, I get a 404.

```
$.get("https://cftestapp1.mydomain.com/rest/api-test/animals");
```

My environment consists of two web servers (cftestapp1 and cftestapp2) behind a load balancer (cftestapps). The web servers are running Coldfusion 11 on Redhat Linux with Apache/Tomcat. Throughout my testing, I tried everything with the load balancer first, and when that didn't work, I focused solely on "cftestapp1" (like the example above). I combed through all of the Coldfusion Administrator settings and the Apache *httpd.conf* file and came up empty.

I cannot find much documentation online or anyone that seems to be experiencing this same problem. If anyone has any insight, please help!! Thanks!

---

Edit:

Each time I make the HTTPS request, the **/etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log** (specified in httpd.conf) shows the following errors:

> [Tue Nov 24 16:34:23 2015] [error] [client my_ip_here] File does not exist: /web/webapps/rest
>   [Tue Nov 24 16:34:23 2015] [error] [client my_ip_here] File does not exist: /web/webapps/opt

**/web/webapps/rest** is the resource I'm requesting; however there is no physical file "rest"; my entries in Coldfusion Administrator's Rest Services should be handling these redirects.

**/web/webapps/opt** appears to be Apache's attempt at serving the 404 page, which is not in the web root but rather deep inside the **/opt** directory.

I've also found this error, which might not be related, since we have never had an issue with our HTTPS requests prior to adding *CF Rest Services*.

> [Tue Nov 24 16:33:12 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)

Below is a snippet from our Apache configuration file (httpd.conf). There are many more lines, but these seem to be the most relevant.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/web/webapps">
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>

Include "/etc/httpd/conf/mod_jk.conf"

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /web/webapps/
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
        SSLProtocol +SSLv3 +TLSv1
        SSLCipherSuite RSA:!EXP:!NULL:+HIGH:-MEDIUM:-LOW
        ErrorLog logs/cfadmin.ssl.error.log
        CustomLog logs/cfadmin.ssl.access.log common
</VirtualHost>

ErrorDocument 404 /opt/cf11/cfusion/wwwroot/CFIDE/administrator/templates/404.cfm
```

It appears as though the HTTPS traffic is not being correctly routed for the 404 and REST Service. But I am able to access all other folders in our **/web/webapps** web root while using HTTPS without any problems.

Comment: Does it work if you simply visit the URL `https://cftestapp1.mydomain.com/rest/api-test/animals` in your browser?  I realize it may give an error or some such but does it resolve? Have you imported the certificate into the java keystore file (cacerts) on your servers?

Comment: Adding the SSL cert to our keystore did not fix it. But hitting the URLs directly in the web browser has proven to be easier: With HTTP, it displays the JSON. With HTTPS, I get Apache's 404 page. But if I break the link after _/rest/_ using HTTP `http://cftestapp1.mydomain.com/rest/api-test-break-me/animals`, I get a blank page. And if I break the link before _/rest/_ using HTTP `https://cftestapp1.mydomain.com/break-me/rest/api-test/animals`, I get Coldfusion's 404 Error. This might be an issue with our Apache configuration. I've updated my question to include more details about that. Thanks!

Comment: Stupid Question #35: what have you got in the **host** field in your Rest Services config in CF Admin? The helper text suggests that you might need a port # in there, do you have two entries (one each for HTTP and HTTPS?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem has been resolved. I found two separate solutions, which were based on the response from mt0 and from Adobe's Help (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/installing/configuring-your-system.html).

**Solution #1**.

Edit **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

I added the following line to my SSL *VirtualHost* directive:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    JKMountFile "/path/to/ColdFusion11/config/wsconfig/1/uriworkermap.properties"
```

However, this would only work if I changed the local IP address (127.0.0.1) to the server's IP address for both the *NameVirtualHost* and *VirtualHost*. (using  `*:443` did not work)

```
NameVirtualHost SERVER_IP_HERE:443
<VirtualHost SERVER_IP_HERE:443>
```

While this solved the problem, I did not want to hard-code the server's IP address inside the config files. So I continued researching and found this alternate solution:

**Solution #2** (preferred).

Edit **/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf** (leaving the httpd.conf file in its original state)

I added the following line to my SSL *VirtualHost* directive, and restarted Apache:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    JKMountFile "/path/to/ColdFusion11/config/wsconfig/1/uriworkermap.properties"
```

This solved my problem.

Thank you everyone for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Your virtual host does not know anything about ColdFusion. If you look in the `/etc/httpd/conf/mod_jk.conf` file, it will have a line that looks like:

```
JKMountFile "/path/to/ColdFusion11/config/wsconfig/1/uriworkermap.properties"
```

Which is being called for the HTTP service (via the `Include "/etc/httpd/conf/mod_jk.conf"` of the config file) but not for the HTTPS service.

All you need to do is copy this line into your `httpd.conf` file within the Virtual Host declaration; like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /web/webapps/
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
  SSLProtocol +SSLv3 +TLSv1
  SSLCipherSuite RSA:!EXP:!NULL:+HIGH:-MEDIUM:-LOW
  ErrorLog logs/cfadmin.ssl.error.log
  CustomLog logs/cfadmin.ssl.access.log common

  JKMountFile "/path/to/ColdFusion11/config/wsconfig/1/uriworkermap.properties"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then the virtual host will know where to find the services.

Comment: Thank you! Your information helped resolve my problem. Including **uriworkermap.properties** in my Apache VirtualHost configuration was necessary to handle my REST services. But I changed my **ssl.conf** rather than **httpd.conf**. I've added an Answer with my exact steps. I appreciate your help!