# Coldfusion 11 - Add Rest API Service host problem

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to set up my first Rest API in Coldfusion 11.
I've successfully registered the service via CFAdmin, when I exclude the host.
But when I try to enter a host, like kobra.xxxxxxx.com, I get the following error:

> Error registering REST service. Please ensure that you have entered a proper mapping and path.
>
> Multiple Host Support For RESTful webservices is not available in this
> edition of ColdFusion server.

How do I know what host to use? Where can I look it up? We are running Apache as web server.

Comment: Just need to added the corresponding rest path project folder with service mapping. Did you check whether your mappings path are correct or not ?

Comment: The service registers fine, when I just enter path (I know the path exists) and mapping. But I do not know which host to use to call the API. That's my problem. And I want to call it remotely.

Comment: You can you that as "localhost".

Comment: But I want to call it from an mobile app. Surely I cannot use "localhost" then?

Comment: If you want to call from mobile then you can use `window.navigator.product` or `cgi.user_agent`. Based on the value you can have some condition to meet the requirements. Hope that make sense. Correct me if I'm wrong understood.

Answer (score 1):

So I found my servername, but it did not work anyway, until I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35139247/4609673), where they suggested to add this row in my virtual host in apache:

> JKMountFile "/path/to/ColdFusion11/config/wsconfig/1/uriworkermap.properties"

And edit it of course with the correct path